# SQL Difference between two rows with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table: rawdata**

```
+---------------------+--------+-------+
|        time         | device | value |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
| 2019-07-19 12:50:00 | a      |   400 |
| 2019-07-19 12:50:00 | a      |   900 |
| 2019-07-19 12:50:00 | a      |   450 |
| 2019-07-19 12:50:00 | b      |   300 |
| 2019-07-19 12:50:00 | b      |   250 |
| 2019-07-19 12:39:00 | a      |   200 |
| 2019-07-19 12:39:00 | a      |   125 |
| 2019-07-19 12:45:00 | b      |   165 |
| 2019-07-19 12:30:00 | a      |    40 |
| 2019-07-19 12:30:00 | a      |    35 |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
```

**Result:**

```
+---------------------+--------+--------+------------------------------+
|        time         | device |  value |                              |
+---------------------+--------+--------+------------------------------+
| 2019-07-19 12:50:00 | a      |    700 | see calculation 1 for detail |
| 2019-07-19 12:50:00 | b      |    135 | see calculation 2 for detail |
| 2019-07-19 12:45:00 | b      |    165 | see calculation 3 for detail |
| 2019-07-19 12:39:00 | a      |    160 | see calculation 4 for detail |
| 2019-07-19 12:30:00 | a      |     40 | see calculation 5 for detail |
+---------------------+--------+--------+------------------------------+
```

**calculation:**
first group by device and time, and find max value of that group. Then find max value of previuos record of same device in group and substract these two max value

**1st** record in group by result would be 12:50:00 and 'a'
Max value of 'a' in 12:50 group = 900, Previous Record of 'a' (or next in list) = 12:39 and its max value = 200

so value= 900-200=**700**

**2nd** record in group by result would be 12:50:00 and 'b'
Max value of 'b' in 12:50:00 group = 300, Previous Record of 'b' (or next in list) = 12:45:00 and its max value = 165

So value= 300-165=**135**

**3rd** record in group by result would be 12:45:00 and 'b'
Max value of 'b' in 12:45:00 group = 165, Previous Record of 'b' (or next in list) = null and its max value = null (0)

So value= 165-0=**165**

**4th** record in group by result would be 12:39:00 and 'a'
Max value of 'a' in 12:39:00 group = 200, Previous Record of 'a' (or next in list) = 12:30:00 and its max value = 40

So value= 200-40=**160**

**5th** record in group by result would be 12:30:00 and 'a'
Max value of 'a' in 12:30:00 group = 40, Previous Record of 'a' (or next in list) = null and its max value = null (0)

So value= 40-0=**40**

Please help me with mssql query for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is aggregation with `lag()`:

```
select time, device, max(value) as max_value,
       (max(value) - lag(max(value)) over (partition by device order by time)) as diff
from rawdata
group by time, device
order by time desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6171558b87184462cbde1fbfc72f7ed0) is a db<>fiddle.