# Lag() function along with group by SQL

Tags: sql, grafana-alerts

I have a table of this format

| time_stamp | sys_id | product_name | valuename | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-03 00:35:00+05:30 | 1 | a | bytes | 10 |
| 2024-01-03 00:35:00+05:30 | 2 | a | bytes | 20 |
| 2024-01-03 00:35:00+05:30 | 3 | a | bytes | 30 |
| 2024-01-03 00:40:00+05:30 | 1 | a | bytes | 20 |
| 2024-01-03 00:40:00+05:30 | 2 | a | bytes | 20 |
| 2024-01-03 00:40:00+05:30 | 3 | a | bytes | 40 |

for a given set of **time_stamp, sys_id, Product_name, valuename** i want to find the difference between **present and previous entry** for that set
and if the difference is equal to 0 then i want to have another columns breach_status for that set to be marked as 1 else 0
hence I'm using lag() function when i give sys_id in where clause it works fine bellow is the sql query and table output

```
    SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(time_stamp) as Time, 
        TO_CHAR(sys_id) as System_ID, 
        product_name, 
        valuename, 
        TO_CHAR(value), 
        (value - LAG(value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY time_stamp)) as diff,
        CASE WHEN value = 0 or diff = 0 or diff is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS breach_status
    FROM table
    WHERE valuename='bytes' and system_id = '2' and 
        time_stamp BETWEEN '2024-01-03 00:35:00' AND '2024-01-03 00:40:00'
    ORDER BY time_stamp
```

| time_stamp | sys_id | product_name | valuename | value | diff | breach_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-03 00:35:00+05:30 | 1 | a | bytes | 10 |  | 0 |
| 2024-01-03 00:35:00+05:30 | 2 | a | bytes | 20 |  | 0 |
| 2024-01-03 00:35:00+05:30 | 3 | a | bytes | 30 |  | 0 |
| 2024-01-03 00:40:00+05:30 | 1 | a | bytes | 20 | 10 | 0 |
| 2024-01-03 00:40:00+05:30 | 2 | a | bytes | 20 | 0 | 1 |
| 2024-01-03 00:40:00+05:30 | 3 | a | bytes | 40 | 10 | 0 |

Here for timestamp = '2024-01-03 00:40:00+05:30', sys_id = 2, product_name = 'a' and valuename = 'bytes' the value difference is 0 hence breach_status for it is 1

But here i want to use group by because there are multiple different combination of timestamp,sys_id,product_name, valuename records.

Hence i wanted to use group by in the above query

```
    SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(time_stamp) as Time, 
        TO_CHAR(system_id) as System_ID, 
        customer_name, 
        valuename, 
        TO_CHAR(max(value)) as val,
        (max(value) - LAG(max(value), 1) OVER (ORDER BY time_stamp)) as diff,
        CASE WHEN value = 0 or diff = 0 or diff is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS breach_status
    FROM table
    WHERE 
        time_stamp BETWEEN '2024-01-03 00:35:00' AND '2024-01-03 00:40:00'
    group by 
        time_stamp,
        system_id,
        customer_name,
        valuename
    ORDER BY time_stamp, diff, breach_status
```

but here instead of using of checking difference between its sets previous entry its checking difference with its above entry

| time_stamp | sys_id | product_name | valuename | value | diff | breach_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-03 00:35:00+05:30 | 1 | a | bytes | 10 |  | 0 |
| 2024-01-03 00:35:00+05:30 | 2 | a | bytes | 20 | 10 | 0 |
| 2024-01-03 00:35:00+05:30 | 3 | a | bytes | 30 | 10 | 0 |
| 2024-01-03 00:40:00+05:30 | 1 | a | bytes | 20 | -10 | 0 |
| 2024-01-03 00:40:00+05:30 | 2 | a | bytes | 20 | 0 | 1 |
| 2024-01-03 00:40:00+05:30 | 3 | a | bytes | 40 | -20 | 0 |

**How I will be using this query**
In the end i will be using this query in grafana dashboard to raise alert based on breach value hence in select statement i want all to be in CHAR hence i converted it using to_char()
but if i convert diff column to char then we cant compare it in the breach condition as its a string not a numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer this [sql difference between two rows with group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117204/sql-difference-between-two-rows-with-group-by)

Here's you need to add partition by

````
    SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(time_stamp) as Time, 
        TO_CHAR(system_id) as System_ID, 
        customer_name, 
        valuename, 
        TO_CHAR(max(value)) as val,
        (max(value) - LAG(max(value), 1) OVER (partition by system_id, customer_name, valuename ORDER BY time_stamp)) as diff,
        CASE WHEN value = 0 or diff = 0 or diff is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS breach_status
    FROM table
    WHERE 
        time_stamp BETWEEN '2024-01-03 00:35:00' AND '2024-01-03 00:40:00'
    group by 
        time_stamp,
        system_id,
        customer_name,
        valuename
    ORDER BY time_stamp```
````

Comment: thanks this worked, what exactly partition by do?